# How to slide up a div 15px to the top

Tags: jquery

```
 $("SomeInputField").keydown(function () {

     $("SomeDiv").css("top", "30px");
 });
```

First this is making a div go 30px from the top

```
 $("SomeInputField").bind("keyup", function () {

     $(this).val() == "" && $("SomeDiv").css("top", "15px");
 });
```

Second, this is making the div go up 15px.

My question: How can I make the div in the second code go up "smoothly", so not "instant" but with some sort of slide up(15px) event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the .animate() jquery function

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
$("SomeDiv").animate({top: 15}, 1000);
```

you can adjust the 1000 to adjust the speed

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you could try [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

For example:

```
$("SomeDiv").animate({ top: 15 });
```